# How to use hyperterminal of XP installed in virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, hyperterminal

I have installed XP in virtual box of my laptop. I installed it because I need hyperterminal for my application. I want to connect my nokia 7210 via usb to a port and to detect it as a COM port so that I can talk to it using AT commands in hyperterminal. I need to verify that my phone is working correctly by this method for my project. 
I have connected my phone. But its showing under Other Devices in Device manager. How can I make it as a COM port? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to install the 7210's cable drivers in your guest operating system, which will  then create the virtual COM port(s) for you. After that, you should be ready to interact with the phone via HyperTerminal.